# Intent a Instagram

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando abrir un perfil de usuario de instagram mediante un alert dialog simple. La idea es que si tiene la aplicación instalada, abra el perfil desde la app. En el caso de no tenerla instalada, que la abra desde el navegador. El problema es que aunque la tengo instalada, sigue abriendo desde el navegador. Este es el código:

```
if(id==R.id.Contacto){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("¡Contáctame!")
                    .setMessage("Esta sección esta diseñada para enviar sugerencias o errores a mi WhatsApp, Facebook o Instagram.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Facebook", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            String fb="fb://page/fulanito";
                            String url="https://wwww.facebook.com/fulanito";
                            try{
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fb)));
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aplicación no instalada. Se abrirá en el explorador.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Instagram", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            String ig="fulanito";
                            String igUrl="https://www.instagram.com/fulanito/";
                            try{
                                Intent iIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
                                iIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName( "com.instagram.android",
                                        "com.instagram.android.activity.UrlHandlerActivity"));
                                iIntent.setData( Uri.parse( "http://instagram.com/p/"+ig+"/") );
                                startActivity(iIntent);
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aplicación no instalada. Se abrirá en el explorador.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(igUrl)));
                            }

                        }
                    });
            alertbox.show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el único problema es el paquete que estas definiendo para la aplicación a abrir que en este caso sería instagram y debe ser:

"`com.instagram.android`"

y la url:

```
"http://instagram.com/_u/<perfil de usuario>"
```

Te sugiero cambiarlos para que abra la aplicación.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/<perfil de usuario>");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

   //No encontró la aplicación, abre la versión web.
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/<perfil de usuario>")));

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me salió en las notificaciones esta respuesta así que no pude agradecerte antes. Me sirvió cambiando esas cosas que me dijiste